# Relation between convergence in $L^2$ and convergence of the integrals

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be an open set of the real numbers.
If $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ that is if $\int_{\Omega} |f_n(x)-f(x)|^2\,dx$ goes to 0 as n goes to infinity, does this imply that $\int_{\Omega} f_n(x)^2\,dx$ goes to $\int_{\Omega} f(x)^2\,dx$ as n goes to infinity ?

Comment: Are $f_n, f$ real? Use the reverse triangle inequality $ \big | ||f_n|| - ||f|| \big| \le ||f_n-f||$

Comment: $||f||= (\int |f|^2)^{1/2}$ so the reverse triangle inequality becomes $ \big | (\int |f_n|^2)^{1/2} - (\int |f|^2)^{1/2} \big | \le (\int |f_n-f|^2)^{1/2}$ from which we infer that  $\int |f_n|^2 \to \int |f|^2$

Comment: In any normed linear space $\|x_n-x\| \to 0$ implies $\|x_n\|\to \|x\|$.

Comment: In any metric space $d(x_n,x)\to 0$ implies $d(x_n,y)\to d(x,y).$